# User selects item in listview and it displays data from text file into a label

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, dictionary

I am trying to write a program that contains a `listview` filled with 4 columns of data from a text file (Name, State, City, Zip in the 4 columns), and when the user clicks a name in the `listview` it displays the name and the phone number (which is in the text file) into 2 labels. 
Here is my code so far:

```
namespace VendorsDictionary
{
    public partial class VendorsDictionary : Form
    {
        public VendorsDictionary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private Dictionary<string,string> vendorPhones = new Dictionary<string,string>();

        private void VendorsDictionary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string currentLine;
            string[] fields = new string[2];
            StreamReader vendorReader = new StreamReader("Vendor.txt");

            while (vendorReader.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                currentLine = vendorReader.ReadLine();
                fields = currentLine.Split(',');

                vendorPhones.Add(fields[1], fields[6]);

                string[] name = { fields[1] };
                string[] city = { fields[3] };
                string[] state = { fields[4] };
                string[] zipcode = { fields[5] };

                for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
                {
                    lvDisplay.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { name[i], city[i], state[i], zipcode[i] }));
                }

            }
            vendorReader.Close();
        }

        private void lvDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lvDisplay.SelectedItems.Count>0)
            {
                ListViewItem item = lvDisplay.SelectedItems[0];
                lblName.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                // lbPhone = ?
                // lblPhone.Text = item.SubItems[].Text; - does not work because phone number is not in the listview 
            }
            else
            {
                lblName.Text = string.Empty;
                lblPhone.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As of now I have everything working properly, except I cannot figure out how to get the phone number from the text file to display into the second label. To get name to display was easy enough because it was in the `listview`, but how would I get the phone number (last column in the text file) to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing phone numbers of the vendors in a dictionary `vendorPhones`.

I am still unsure of the format and structure of the data stored in the file and why you loop for `name.length`.

If my assumption, that the vendor names are unique, you can get the phone number of the selected vendor from the dictionary as following.

```
private void lvDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lvDisplay.SelectedItems.Count>0)
    {
        ListViewItem item = lvDisplay.SelectedItems[0];
        lblName.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
        lblPhone.Text = vendorPhones[item.SubItems[0].Text]; // Get the phone number from dictionary by using the vendor name.
    }
    else
    {
        lblName.Text = string.Empty;
        lblPhone.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```